# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined on some pages

Tags: javascript

```js
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  // ... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == x.length - 1) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
    document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  }
  // ... and run a function that displays the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n);
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 0 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form... :
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    //...the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i,
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class to the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;  
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;


/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
.tab {
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
.step.finish {
y  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
  <h1>Register:</h1>
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">Name:
    <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="fname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="lname"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Contact Info:
    <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="email"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Birthday:
    <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dd"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''" name="nn"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" name="yyyy"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Login Info:
    <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="uname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="pword" type="password"></p>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

This script is working fine on the page where i run it, but on other pages i got the next error:"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined". I supose that the problem appear because the script doesn't find the necessaire element (variable) in other pages, but in the page where the script is used, the problem doesn't appear beacause the necessaire element is in this page. How to solve the problem for avoiding the problem that i described?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `x` is defined or not that holds the element with class name `tab`:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
//check here if x is defined and it has elements
x[n].style.display = "block";
```

So your code will have a `if` block to prevent that runtime error:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
if(x.length){
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: Also, check for existence of other elements, like here: `getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = //...`

Comment: @mbojko yeah OP really needs to consider such thing everywhere. Nice point added.

Comment: @Ankit Agarwal  how to change : <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button> <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button> , using add event listener? And in the same time avoidind using java script code in Html file.

Comment: I solved. `var a = document.getElementById("prevBtn");
var b = document.getElementById("nextBtn");
if (a) {
  a.addEventListener("click", function() {
    nextPrev(-1);
  });
}
if (b) {
  b.addEventListener("click", function() {
    nextPrev(1);
  });
}' `

Comment: @Asking great. It is nice to hear that. Keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

I have added error handling and check for undefined in his code. Its better handle edge cases like this. Also, it is advisable to store operations like document.getElementById in a variable for future use.

```js
var currentTab = 0;
showTab(currentTab);

function showTab(n) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  if (x && x[n]) {
    x[n].style.display = "block"; //checking for undefined
  }
  var prevBtn = document.getElementById("prevBtn")
  if (prevBtn) {
    if (n == 0) {
      prevBtn.style.display = "none"; //Checking for undefined
    } else {
      prevBtn.style.display = "inline";
    }
  }
  var nextBtn = document.getElementById("nextBtn");
  if (nextBtn) {
    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
      nextBtn.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      nextBtn.style.display = "inline";
      nextBtn.innerHTML = "Next";
      document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    }
  }
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  if (x && x[currentTab]) {
    x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  }
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (!x || !x[i]) {
      continue;
    }
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  if (x && x[n]) {
    x[n].className += " active";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

.tab {
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.step.finish {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
  <h1>Register:</h1>
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">Name:
    <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="fname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="lname"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Contact Info:
    <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="email"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Birthday:
    <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dd"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''" name="nn"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" name="yyyy"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Login Info:
    <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="uname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="pword" type="password"></p>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```